# Flipping div's with onclick

Tags: javascript, rotatetransform

ok, sorry for amateur status but i need a little help. All i want to do is have a div(mian) with 2 divs in it (div-front), (div-back), that when I click main div the div-front and div back rotate. then when main div is clicked again they rotate back.

`<div id="main">
     <div id="front">Some text</div>
     <div id="back">Some other text</div>
</div>`

this is kinda the setup I'm referring to. I have tried using a toggleClass but I assume I just dont understand it enough. Any Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html

Comment: Although this is informative to the accual making of the divs, there is no mention of adding the click function to it. the click function is what i need to understand. Thank you for responce.

Comment: Sure there is. Read the page, go through the examples, and look at the code. It's all there. We're not going to spoon feed you the answers when it appears you've done nothing more than create three divs.

Comment: +1 @j08691 for extracting the usage concept based on OP's content.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a click-listener. When the element is clicked, it will run the function you define, and that is where you'd have your call to `toggleClassName`

```
document.getElementById('flip').addEventListener( 'click', function(){
    card.toggleClassName('flipped');
  }, false);
```

Sources:

http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/card-02-slide-flip.html
http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/js/flip-card.js

More on event listeners in javascript:

developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: Thank you for actually reading and understanding the question. Guidance is what I need and the event listener link helped. Thank you again for your ability to understand a question and not just respond from the hip.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very straight forward example using JQuery.

https://jsfiddle.net/james2doyle/qsQun/

```
<button onclick="flip()">flip the card</button>
<section class="container">
  <div class="card" onclick="flip()">
    <div class="front">1</div>
    <div class="back">2</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

and the JS

```
function flip() {
    $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
}
```

Comment: Your code works great (+1) . . . for one image, but when used with multiple images, they all flip at the same time, not just the clicked one, what should i do to make your code work with each image individually? I mean, flip ONLY the clicked image and not the others. Thanks in advance ☻